# Based on variables return columns, but show blank values and don't use conditions

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

This is a bare bones strip of my actual code, but I would like to undestand how to do this so I can apply it throughout. I have code like this:

```
declare

use_t3 varchar2(1): = 'N'; //Y or N
use_t4 varchar2(1): = 'N'; //Y or N

begin

INSERT INTO MY_BIG_TABLE
SELECT
     t3.qid AS "QID",
    (SELECT t5.flag FROM t5 WHERE(t5.qid = t4.qid)) AS "FLAG"
    FROM
      t1 p,
      t2 pm,
      t3 pms,
      t4 pmo
WHERE
      t1.id = t2.qid
      AND t3.day = 'Monday'
      AND t2.id = t4.pmd_id(+)
      AND t4.date IS NULL
end;
```

Now I have two variables:

```
use_t3
use_t4
```

If use_t3 and use_t4 are both equal to 'Y' (which means Yes, use these tables) then the query should be run as is shown exactly as both tables should be used (only either use_t1 or use_t2 can be equal to 'N', which means there will always be one which is qual to 'Y').

If use_t3 = 'N' and use_t4 = 'Y' then I would like the t3.qid column to still show but to return null, and for the condition:

```
t3.day = 'Monday'
```

to not be used.

If use_t3 = 'Y' and use_t4 = 'N' then I would like the "FLAG" column to return blank values, and the conditions:

```
t2.id = t4.pmd_id(+)
AND t4.date IS NULL
```

to not be used.

I hope this makes sense.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally join to a table, a case statement in an ANSI LEFT JOIN should work as long as your export is ok with a Left Join on both tables.

```
declare

use_t3 varchar2(1): = 'N'; //Y or N
use_t4 varchar2(1): = 'N'; //Y or N

begin

INSERT INTO MY_BIG_TABLE
SELECT
     t3.qid AS "QID",
    (SELECT T5.FLAG FROM T5 WHERE(T5.QID = T4.QID)) AS "FLAG"
    FROM           T1 /*P*/ 
              JOIN T2 /*PM*/  ON T1.ID = T2.QID
         LEFT JOIN T3 /*pms*/ ON CASE WHEN USE_T3 = 'Y' AND T3.DAY = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
         LEFT JOIN t4 /*pmo*/ ON CASE WHEN USE_T4 = 'Y' AND T2.ID = T4.PMD_ID AND t4.date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
end;
```

Otherwise, you'll probably have to do multiple IF THEN statements to cover each option.

```
declare

USE_T3 VARCHAR2(1): = 'N'; --//Y or N
use_t4 varchar2(1): = 'N'; --//Y or N

BEGIN
--If both are 'Y' ---------------------
IF USE_T3 = 'Y' AND USE_T4 = 'Y' then
INSERT INTO MY_BIG_TABLE
SELECT
     t3.qid AS "QID",
    (SELECT t5.flag FROM t5 WHERE(t5.qid = t4.qid)) AS "FLAG"
    FROM
      t1 p,
      t2 pm,
      t3 pms,
      t4 pmo
WHERE
      t1.id = t2.qid
      AND t3.day = 'Monday'
      AND t2.id = t4.pmd_id(+)
      AND T4.DATE IS NULL
END IF;

--If USE_T3 is 'Y' And USE_T4 is 'N' ---------------------
if IF USE_T3 = 'Y' AND USE_T4 = 'N' then
INSERT INTO MY_BIG_TABLE
SELECT
     t3.qid AS "QID",
    NULL AS "FLAG"
    FROM
      t1 p,
      t2 pm,
      t3 pms
WHERE
      t1.id = t2.qid
      AND t3.day = 'Monday'
END IF;

--If USE_T3 is 'N' And USE_T4 is 'Y' ---------------------
IF USE_T3 = 'N' AND USE_T4 = 'Y' then
INSERT INTO MY_BIG_TABLE
SELECT
     NULL AS "QID",
    (SELECT t5.flag FROM t5 WHERE(t5.qid = t4.qid)) AS "FLAG"
    FROM
      t1 p,
      t2 pm,
      t4 pmo
WHERE
      t1.id = t2.qid
      AND t2.id = t4.pmd_id(+)
      AND T4.DATE IS NULL
end if;

end;
```

Comment: But don't the tables still show then? For example if use_t4 = 'N' then the specific where clause won't run, but wont t4 table still be called since it is still in the FROM clause?

Comment: You're correct. A conditional WHERE will still use all tables specified in the FROM section. I've changed my answer to show two different ways to have conditional joins.

Answer (score 0):

you may use string concatenation..

```
    DECLARE

      use_t3 varchar2(1): = 'N'; //Y or N
      use_t4 varchar2(1): = 'N'; //Y or N
      plsql_block VARCHAR2(500);

    BEGIN

      -- Dynamic PL/SQL block invokes insert statement:
      plsql_block := 'INSERT INTO MY_BIG_TABLE ' 
                   ||' SELECT ';

      If use_t3 = 'Y' then
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' t3.qid AS "QID", ';
      Else
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' null AS "QID", ';
      End if;

      If use_t4 = 'Y' 
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' (SELECT t5.flag FROM t5 WHERE(t5.qid = t4.qid)) AS "FLAG"';

      Else
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' '''' AS "FLAG", ';
      End if;


      plsql_block := plsql_block || ' FROM t1 p, t2 pm ';

      If use_t3 = 'Y' then
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' ,t3 pms ';
      End if

      If use_t4 = 'Y' then
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' ,t4 pmo ';
      End if

      plsql_block := plsql_block || ' WHERE t1.id = t2.qid ';

      If use_t3 = 'Y' then
          plsql_block := 
              plsql_block || ' AND t3.day = ''Monday'' ';
      End if

      If use_t4 = 'Y' then
          plsql_block := 
            plsql_block || ' AND t2.id = t4.pmd_id(+) AND t4.date IS NULL ' ;
      End if    

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block;   
   END;
```